# Here.com API isoChrone Is Self Interesecting Polygon

Tags: polygon, here-api

Newbie question.

Has anybody run into isoChrone (Drive Time Polygons) where the resulting points represent a self-intersecting polygon?

I presume this is to be expected with the algorithm and underlying network data?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I did not expect an isoChrone request to ever result in a self-intersecting polygon for certain map locations.  Comments, insight?  Just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the isoline calculation done by Here API. Do you have a specific scenario where you observe such a self intersecting ploygon ?